# .Net 6 Preview 6 - The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception - DivideByZeroException

Tags: winforms, .net-core, .net-6.0

I've compiled a solid/stabel solution against .Net 6, and it compiles ok, with no errors nor warnings, I can manipulate the designer part of the main form, but when I launch it I receive:

```
   CoreCLR Version: 6.0.21.35212
.NET Version: 6.0.0-preview.6.21352.12
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
   at System.Math.DivRem(Int64 a, Int64 b, Int64& result) in System.Private.CoreLib.dll:token 0x600046a+0x0
   at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.ImageInfo.AdvanceAnimationBy(Int64 milliseconds) in System.Drawing.Common.dll:token 0x6000bed+0x31
   at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.AnimateImages() in System.Drawing.Common.dll:token 0x60002e0+0x3d
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartHelper.Callback(Object state) in System.Private.CoreLib.dll:token 0x600288d+0x0
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) in System.Private.CoreLib.dll:token 0x6002a2d+0x40
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) in System.Private.CoreLib.dll:token 0x6002a2d+0x80
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback() in System.Private.CoreLib.dll:token 0x600280f+0xe
```

I do not have any "division" in the code, and I'm not able to debug because it seems that the error is part of the dotnet classes.

Can you help me with that? I'm just trying to anticipate for the porting from .Net Core 5 to .Net Core 6.

Comment: Remove animated Images or replace with a static surrogate (the ImageAnimator class has being edited a bit, the fixed time frame somewhat reduced and the `TotalAnimationTime` Property value re-calculated in a different manner. This Property appears to be set to `0` for some reason). -- Note that you don't have the latest preview.

Comment: I use the .Net Core 6 Preview 6 of 14th July, and I do not use or reference ImageAnimator Class. thank you, btw.

Comment: You don't need to add a reference to `ImageAnimator`. That class is used by all Controls that can show animated images (e.g., PictureBox, Button, Label).

Comment: Thank you! your comment helped to figure out the issue: external control that use an animated image.

Comment: Just a quick note, why should this question be evaluated as - 1? If this site isn't for asking... For  me it wasn't so trivial knowing that an animated gif in core 6 will cause a division by zero and with the debugger, even unchecking "just my code", you are not able to catch the source...

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug (regression) in Core 6.0 P6.
Opened in gitub:
[dotnet/runtime - Animated Gif - division by zero #55972](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/55972)

Many thanks to [jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) for the help